# upload formdata to node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I want to save images base64 to db (mongodb) but don't know how to get the request in node.js.

This is my cilent side code

```
$('.imageUp').change(function(){

       upload(new FormData(this))
})

function upload(formData){
$.ajax({
        url: '/upload_img',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false
    })
}
```

Then what should I do in node?

```
router.post('/upload_img', function(req, res, next) {
// what to do here? how to get the post file? I'm going to save it to mongodb
});
```

Comment: I know its maybe not your question concept but i prefer using iframe in upload files

Create Iframe in runtime
Create form with its attributes in this body of the Iframe with ('enctype', 'multipart/form-data')

Comment: Not the solution to your question `FormData()` takes an optional `form` element as its argument, not an `input` element. You should probably be using `new FormData()` and `formData.append()`.

Comment: @JLRishe I don't get you

Comment: In your `change` handler you are calling `new FormData(this)`. In that location, `this` is the file `input`, is it not?

Comment: @JLRishe yes, why not?

Comment: @EuniceChia Like I already said, the `FormData()` constructor only takes `<form>` elements as its argument, not `<input>` elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData

Comment: @JLRishe can you create a solution for this?

Comment: instead of `this` I should pass `event.target.files[0]`??

Comment: I just want to send the file from front to the server.

Comment: @EuniceChia See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Comment: No, do this: `var formData = new FormData(); formData.append(this); upload(formData);`. I already said this too.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.

Comment: @JLRishe Are two parameters are required for `.append()`?

Comment: @guest271314 I don;t know man, I paste the error here

Comment: @EuniceChia Yes, two parameters are required to be passed to `.append()`; key and value. Try `var data = new FormData(); data.append("file", this.files[0], this.files[0].name); console.log(data.get("file"))`

Comment: what's next in node.js?

Comment: What do you mean? What have you tried? What is `res` at `nodejs` following above process?

Comment: @guest271314 is this https://jsfiddle.net/y8mm4u9o/ correct? Im seeing empty object for `FormData`

Comment: @EuniceChia `javascript` at jsfiddle does set value to `this.files[0]` or call `formData.get("file")` as mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418950/upload-formdata-to-node-js?noredirect=1#comment64245086_38418950 ; see https://jsfiddle.net/y8mm4u9o/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use `.append()` at `FormData` object at client side to pass `FormData` containing user selected `File` object to `upload`

```
$(".imageUp").change(function() {
  var data = new FormData();
  // requires two parameters to be passed
  data.append("file", this.files[0]);
  upload(data)
})
```